# Parsing through JSON file with python and selecting multiple values on certain conditions

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON file.

```
{  
   "reviewers":[  
      {  
         "user":{  
            "name":"keyname",
            "emailAddress":"John@email",
            "id":3821,
            "displayName":"John Doe",
            "active":true,
            "slug":"jslug",
            "type":"NORMAL",
            "link":{  
               "url":"/users/John",
               "rel":"self"
            },
         },
         "role":"REVIEWER",
         "approved":true
      },
      {  
         "user":{  
            "name":"keyname2",
            "emailAddress":"Harry@email",
            "id":6306,
            "displayName":"Harry Smith",
            "active":true,
            "slug":"slug2",
            "link":{  
            "type":"NORMAL",
               "url":"/users/Harry",
               "rel":"self"
            },
         },
         "role":"REVIEWER",
         "approved":false
      }
   ],
}
```

Initially, I was using a snippet of code that would go through and grab the full names of the reviewers.

```
def get_reviewers(json):
    reviewers = ""
    for key in json["reviewers"]:
        reviewers += key["user"]["displayName"] + ", "
    reviewers = reviewers[:-2]
    return reviewers
```

which would return `"John Doe, Harry Smith"`. However, now I'm trying to get it so that the script will return a (A) next to the name of the user if their tag equals true `"approved"=true`.

So for example the code above would get the names, then see that John's approved tag is true and Harry's is false, then return `"John Doe(A), Harry Smith"`. I'm just not sure where to even begin to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is what I've been trying so far but obviously it isn't working as I'd like it to.

```
def get_reviewers(stash_json):
    reviewers = ""
    for key in stash_json["reviewers"]:
        if stash_json["reviewers"][0]["approved"] == true:
            reviewers += key["user"]["displayName"] + "(A)" + ", "
        else:
            reviewers += key["user"]["displayName"] + ", "
    reviewers = reviewers[:-2]
    return reviewers
```

which outputs `Jason Healy(A), Joan Reyes(A)`

This is what my `stash_json` outputs when put through pprint.

Comment: I think you want `== True`, not `== "true"`, assuming you're parsing the JSON properly.

Comment: With the suggested correction, the line `if stash_json["reviewers"][0]["approved"]:` will always have the same result, since you've fixed the list index there. Perhaps you want `if key['approved']:`?

Comment: Btw, don't explicitly compare to `True`. The truthiness of the value itself is enough: use `if stash_json["reviewers"][0]["approved"]:` instead of `if stash_json["reviewers"][0]["approved"] == True:`.

Comment: I think `if key["approved"]:` is what you want.

Comment: @Evert I see what you're saying but am having a little bit of trouble actually implementing it, would you be able to post an example? Thanks.

Comment: @smarx, OP `stash_json["reviewers"]` is a list. `key` is really the incorrect term here, and `item` would have been better.

Comment: Hmm using `if key["approved"]:` returns `John Doe(A), Harry Smith(A)`

Edit: I feel like it's only checking the approved value for John

Comment: Your JSON file is incorrect, as it contains trailing commas. What code/module are you using to read the JSON file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something along the lines of this:

```
def get_reviewers(stash_json):
    reviewers = ""
    for item in stash_json["reviewers"]:
        if item["approved"]:
            reviewers += item["user"]["displayName"] + "(A)" + ", "
        else:
            reviewers += item["user"]["displayName"] + ", "
    reviewers = reviewers[:-2]
    return reviewers
```

I think part of your confusion comes from the fact that "reviewers" is a `list` of `dict` elements, and each `dict` element has a key-value `approved`, but also a key "user" which value itself is another `dict`.

---

Read the JSON file carefully, and for debugging purposes, use plenty of

```
print(...)
print(type(...))   # whether something is a dict, list, str, bool etc
```

or

```
from pprint import pprint    # pretty printing
pprint(...)
```

Comment: On my end that's returning `John Doe(A), Harry Smith(A)`, but i'm getting closer to the result I want.

Comment: @O.Watson That'll be because you're using a different JSON reader than the Python `stdlib` module. If I use the `stdlib` `json` module, I can't even read your JSON file, as it contains trailing commas. Presumably, your JSON reader translates `true` to something like `"true"`, so possibly you need to change that comparison (e.g. `if item["approved"] == "true":`). Better, however, is to fix your JSON file and use the stdlib json module instead to read it.

Comment: `==`, not `=`, but yeah, hard to know what's going on without seeing the code that parses the JSON

Comment: @smarx Tx; just within the 2 mins grace editing period. Are typos in comments allowed? ;-)

Comment: Oh my god of course, bit of a silly mistake, let me post the proper JSON

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good place to use `join` and list comprehension:

```
def get_reviewers(stash_json):
   return ", ".join([item['user']['displayName'] + ('(A)' if item['approved'] else '') for item in stash_json['reviewers']])
```